# Using `std::vector` as default for template template parameter

Tags: templates, c++11, anonymous-types, optional-parameters

Suppose `foo` is a template that takes a container type, which itself has one template argument to specify the type of its values:

```
template <template<typename val_t> class container_t>
struct foo;
```

For convenience, `foo` shall take `std::vector` as a default container.  Trouble is that formally `std::vector` formally has two arguments of which the second has a default.  This means `... container = std::vector` does not work.

A solution with C++11 would be to define a template alias:

```
template<typename val_t> using vec_dummy = std::vector<val_t>;
template <template<typename val_t> class container_t = vec_dummy>
struct foo;
```

I don't like, for readability (you have to search `vec_dummy`) and also for aesthetic reasons (there's no reason to name that type).

Is there a way to somehow define the template alias anonymously?  Other approaches to the problem are of course also warmly welcome.

**PS:** In reality, `foo` uses an internal data type as value type for the provided container, so

```
template <typename container_t = std::vector<int>> struct foo;
```

is not an option.

Comment: I might have missed something, but what's wrong with `template <template <class, class> class Container = std::vector>`?

Comment: @black because then you couldn't use containers which only take one template parameter, or more than two.

Comment: That's precisely, the reason. Thanks TartanLlama for answering for me :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make `container_t` a variadic template template parameter (*shiver*).

```
template <template<typename val_t, typename...> class container_t = std::vector>
struct foo;
```

This way you can focus on the value type, but still maintain any allocator template parameters etc.

Comment: Yeah, you need variadic templates. I thought about SFINAE-ing on the `Alloc` parameter, but it cannot work as you don't have the container `container_t` parameter yet.

Comment: I tried it in VC++ and got `error C2976: 'std::vector' : too few template arguments`, so it seems that the defaults get ignored. Is it standard C++? For reference, here's the complete snippet:
`template <template<typename val_t, typename...> class container_t = std::vector> struct foo { container_t<int> cont; };`

Comment: @Xlea what version of VC++ are you using? Pretty sure that's valid C++11 and it works in [GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d7975dac87b366d) and [Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/addd699bce3098f4).

Comment: @Xlea MSVC++ is late for modern C++; variadic templates are, specifically, available on MSVC++ > 2013.

Comment: It's VS 2013, so that might explain why it doesn't work with my setup. Thanks, guys!

Comment: Note:  this won't work with `std::array`, since it has a non-type template parameter.